# Reconstitue original xts within a templated quantmod newTA call

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

I'm working on a relative return function to compare prices a ticker to a benchmark. The function is quite simple: `Cl(x)/Cl(Benchmark)`.

I'm having trouble aligning the index (dates) of the input to the benchmark. I think I've narrowed this down to a timezone issue when I try to interpret the data passed to my TA function into an xts object. For this, I'm using `x <- try.xts(x, error = as.matrix)`. However, this seems to miss the timezone from the original data.

Any ideas how to get the timezone from the original data from within a `quantmod` `newTA()` templated call?

The TA function:

```
TestTA <- function(x) {
        x <- try.xts(x, error = as.matrix)
        print(paste("Input to TA", indexClass(x), indexTZ(x), sep = ": "))
        SPY <- getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign = FALSE, src = "yahoo")
        print(paste("call wihitn TA", indexClass(SPY), indexTZ(SPY), sep = ": "))
        m <- merge(Cl(x), Cl(SPY), all = TRUE)
        print(tail(m))
        return(Cl(x)/Cl(SPY)) # This is what i really want to do, but cant until i get the dates to line up
}

addTestTA <- newTA(TestTA)
```

The Test:

```
IBM <- getSymbols("IBM", auto.assign = FALSE, src = "yahoo")
paste("Raw IBM DATA", indexClass(IBM), indexTZ(IBM), sep = ": ")
chartSeries(IBM, TA = "addTestTA()")
```

This outputs the following interim result (during testing)

```
                    IBM.Close SPY.Close
2017-01-24 17:00:00        NA    229.57
2017-01-25 00:00:00    178.29        NA
2017-01-25 17:00:00        NA    229.33
2017-01-26 00:00:00    178.66        NA
2017-01-26 17:00:00        NA    228.97
2017-01-27 00:00:00    177.30        NA
```

As you can see, there are time elements cropping up in the index due to timezone that are cause misalignment.

Answer (score 0):

Ethan, I suggest to create the benchmark series outside of the function call as everytime you call the function you have to download it again. My solution would be the following:

download the benchmark:

```
benchmark <- "SPY" # keep the benchmark flexible 
bm <- getSymbols(benchmark,from = '2012-01-01', auto.assign = FALSE)
```

the function: 
`last` and `NROW` ensure that  benchmark and instrument have same starting day. If benchmark and instrument trade at different exchanges and have different trading days (exchange holidays) you have to adapt the code accordingly  and implement some error handling ( i.e.checking of dimensions etc.) In your example I assume that benchmark and instrument are traded on the same days.

```
TestTA <- function(x) {
  return(Cl(x)/last(Cl(bm),NROW(x)))
}
addTestTA <- newTA(TestTA)
```

Let’s download `AMZN` with a different starting day:

```
getSymbols("AMZN",from = '2014-01-01')
```

and create the chart

```
chartSeries(AMZN, TA = "addTestTA()")
```

[image]

Note: Consider excess returns instead of price ratio. It is more useful as   the strength of the “indicator value" can be compared between different instruments.

*UPDATE*: `using merge` and `addTA`

This flexible solution makes it easy to play around with different tickers and/or benchmarks:

```
relStrength <- function(x,bm){ #x: instrument OHLC object, bm: benchmark OHLC object
  m <- merge(Ad(x),Ad(bm), join ='inner')
  RS <- m[,1]/m[,2]
}
ticker <- 'IBM'
Instr <- cbind(Instr <- getSymbols(ticker,from='2014-01-01',auto.assign = FALSE),RS=relStrength(Instr,bm = SPY))
chartSeries(Instr,TA='addTA(Instr[,7])')
```

Comment: thx @hvollmeier. thats roughly the workaround ive been using. what i actually do is merge the benchmark as a column onto the price xts and then pass in the names/ordinals of the columns holding the price and benchmark to my RelPerf function. As you point out, that allows me to work out the alignment upfront. still bugs me that I cant get back to my original data. feels like im doing something wrong